# How to achieve task continuation in c# 4.0

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, task, continuations

I have a collection of modules to be initialised and 3 of the modules take a long time whereas others take very little time to initialise. Currently if do all of them on the same thread it takes a lot of time e.g.

```
foreach (var m in modules)
{
     var md = m;
     md.Initialise();
}
```

so I am trying something like

```
foreach (var m in modules)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
                                      var md = m;
                                      md.Initialise();
                              }, TaskCreationOptions.Longrunning);

}
```

Also tried:

```
Parallel.ForEach(modules, m => m.Initialize());
```

Neither of these works because it won't wait for all modules to be initialised.
I need all modules to be initialised before the UI thread can continue otherwise the UI will start up very quickly after the first module initialised and UI becomes an empty shell due to other modules still uninitialized. Is there any way to achieve each module initialised on separate thread and the main thread will wait until they are ALL initialised? Hope I have made myself clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your `foreach` in parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(modules, m => m.Initialize());
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that I tried this already and it didn't work. I think Parallel.ForEach in this case won't do continuation i.e. if one module takes 1 sec to initialise and another one takes 10 sec to initialise then the main thread will only 'pause' for 1 sec rather than 10 sec.

Comment: @stt106 That isn't true. `Parallel.ForEach` blocks until all items are processed. Maybe you mistakenly tried usong `Parallel.ForEach` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` together?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov sorry you are right. I was doing something silly though not using parallel and task together. I think this answered the question I asked though it doesn't fully solve my problem but I guess the problem now is not about parallelism so I am marking this as the correct answer.